# ActionResult Edit for image using MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have successfully Save and display images using

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            TestEntities db = new TestEntities();
            string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);


            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);


            Client newRecord = new Client();
            newRecord.TitelAr = Request.Form["TitelAr"];
            newRecord.descriptionAr = Request.Form["descriptionAr"];
            //newRecord.DateTime = Request.Form["DateTime"];
            newRecord.Img = ImageName;
            db.Client.Add(newRecord);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }


        return RedirectToAction("../Clients/Index/");
    }
```

but I can't change the image with Edit view , the following code save the same image

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Client client, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var productInDb = db.Client.Find(client.ID);
            productInDb.TitelAr = client.TitelAr;
            productInDb.descriptionAr = client.descriptionAr;

            if (client.Img != null)
            {
                string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
                productInDb.Img = ImageName;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(client);
    }
```

I need to change it ,please help me to change the images in Edit View , 
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean _edit images_?

Comment: I think he means upload another image in place of exisitng one

Comment: What is the problem you are having ? Your action method code seems to save the new image and update the db record.

Answer (score 0):

You should control file object.

try

```
if (file != null)
            {
                string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string physicalPath = Server.MapPath("~/images/" + ImageName);
                productInDb.Img = ImageName;
            }
```